# Electron tray.displayBalloon() not working from async calls

Tags: windows, electron

This works:

```
tray.displayBalloon({ title: 'my app', 'content': 'Access app settings from tray menu.' });
```

This does not:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        tray.displayBalloon({ title: 'my app', 'content': 'Access app settings from tray menu.' });
     }, 100);
```

Why?

P.S. I'm running it on Win10 and Electron 1.8.1

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this [is a known 'wontfix'](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5844)

The solution is to provide an icon in the options for the displayBalloon call.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    let img = nativeImage.createFromPath('some path to a png works');
    tray.displayBalloon({
        title: 'my app',
        content: 'Access app settings from tray menu.',
        icon: img
    });
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your application is running at the moment when you call `tray.displayBalloon`. To prevent application quit you can handle `will-quit` event (see [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app))

```
app.on('will-quit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

Calling `event.preventDefault()` in `will-quit` event handler will prevent the default behaviour, which is terminating the application.